# Added new autocomplete words to Notepad++ html.xml but they don't autocomplete?

Tags: notepad++

I edited the html.xml file in Notepad++ i've added one new line to test if it would autocomplete but it's not. I added `<KeyWord name="form-control" />`. This isn't an html tag but a CSS class. So while I was typing `<div class="form.....` I get the autocomplete popop which has the word form, but not this keyword. Autcomplete is on and works. Do I have to edit some other file? The file i'm editing has HTML set as the language.

Comment: Which HTML.xml file did you edit? There's one in langs directory for syntax highlighting and another in API/autocomplete (something like that) that is what you want.

Comment: @NeilNeyman `Notepad++\plugins\APIs\html.xml` is the file I edited

Comment: Is it possible you need both?  Also dumb question but just to rule out anything did you restart notepad++ after editing?

Comment: @NeilNeyman I don't see any other HTML files. Yes I restarted multiple times, verified my edits were saved, loaded other language files, reloaded HTML, opened closed files loaded HTML again etc.

Comment: Sorry.  langs.xml is the other file you want to edit, not langs directory.

Comment: @NeilNeyman I had opened this file earlier, overlooked the fact it scrolls way over to the right and it contains words from every language file! I'll try this tomorrow feel free to post an answer and i'll mark it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making this an answer.

Try editing both langs.xml and html.xml with the words you want to add. Save, restart, say a prayer and hopefully it works!

Comment: Awesome that's it, to autocomplete new words. The word must be in both the API language file `html.xml` as well as in the `langs.model` file